# Adding where clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am new to Linq. Please help.On this query i need to add where clause (like `EMPLOYEE_ID==10`).db stands dbcontext.

```
    var query = db.EmpQualifications.Select(EmpQu => new {
EMP_QUALI_ID = EmpQu.EMP_QUALI_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID = EmpQu.EMPLOYEE_ID,
 }).OrderBy(D => D.EMP_QUALI_ID);
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: you always want to add the `Where` before anything else :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply Add the `where` clause before `Select`

```
var results = db.EmpQualifications
                   .Where(r=> r.EMPLOYEE_ID == 10)
                   .Select(EmpQu => 
                             new {
                                 EMP_QUALI_ID = EmpQu.EMP_QUALI_ID,
                                 EMPLOYEE_ID = EmpQu.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
                                 })
                   .OrderBy(D => D.EMP_QUALI_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like;

```
var query = db.EmpQualification
               .Where(e => e.MPLOYEE_ID==10)
               .Select...
```

You can read more information fromm [`where clause - Query Keywords`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx)

> The where clause is a filtering mechanism. It can be positioned almost
>   anywhere in a query expression, **except it cannot be the first or last
>   clause**. A where clause may appear either before or after a group
>   clause depending on whether you have to filter the source elements
>   before or after they are grouped.

Answer (score 0):

add the `Where` extension method just efore the `Select`

```
var query = db.EmpQualifications.Where(x => x.MPLOYEE_ID==10).Select....
```